# Artificial objects longer than 40 meters in space

Tags: dimensions

The ISS with its 73m x 108m [Integrated truss structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Truss_Structure), apparently, is the largest (by dimensions) artificial object in space.

I know about the [Krab experiment](http://journals.ru/attach/653/65203/974979.jpg) which produced two self assembly rings of 20m diameter, attached to a Progress spacecraft. That gives 40m x 20m.

Both Space Shuttle orbiter and Mir station were a bit shorter than 40m.

Neither of thin object such as [IKAROS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKAROS) solar sail (20m) or [Znamya reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Znamya_%28space_mirror%29) (20m) come even close.

The [Inflatable Antenna Experiment's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflatable_Antenna_Experiment) struts were shorter (28m) too.

So the question is: **have there been any (other than ISS) artificial objects longer than 40 meters in orbit?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That one is easy: http://www-istp.gsfc.nasa.gov/Education/wtether.html

There have been a number of [space tether missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tether_missions), the longest (verified!) was the TSS-1R on February 25, 1996, when the Columbia in the STS-75 flight unrolled the tether to 19.7 km.

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq4brZBqXvU

References:

- http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/missions/sts-75/mission-sts-75.html
- http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/missions/sts-75/sts-75-day-04-highlights.html

Answer (score 4):

The satellites are classified, so details are speculative, but it is believed that the Magnum/Orion and Mentor SIGINT satellites have parabolic antennae around 100 m in diameter.

Comment: This has got me really intrigued, so here we go: [What is the largest antenna deployed in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32884/12102)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question to broaden the context a little bit.

The 60 meter [ADAM mast](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/mast.html) was the larges *rigid* structure of its time (STS-77, 16 February 2000).

[image]

To quote the JPL description:

*Unique latches on the diagonal members of the truss allowed the mechanism to deploy bay-by-bay out of the mast canister to a length of 60 meters (200 feet). The canister housed the mast during launch and landing, and it also deployed and retracted the mast.*