# Why is "Terminator Tape" electrically conductive?

Tags: artificial-satellite, debris, atmospheric-drag, deorbit

A 230 foot long [tape](https://www.tethers.com/taking-out-the-space-trash-tethers-unlimited-announces-successful-operation-of-space-debris-removal-device/) deployed from the satellite [Prox-1](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/prox-1.htm) greatly reduced how long it took to deorbit.  The tape was [described](https://www.space.com/space-junk-removal-terminator-tape-satellite-test.html) as electrically conductive.

Was that property intended to help the satellite deorbit faster, or was the tape's atmospheric drag sufficient?

(Illustrations suggest that the tape is about 70 m x 0.1 m, or 7 m^2.  It weighs "less than 2 pounds" or roughly 700 g, for an areal density of 100 g/m^2.  Mylar is 1.4 g/cm^3, so if this is Mylar, its thickness is 0.07 mm = "2 mil," industrially common when foil-covered like a party balloon.  But why foil-covered instead of just pure polyester?)

Comment: A chapter in Randall Munroe's "How To" says that an A4 sheet of paper would survive re-entry without burning up.  Should we expect strips of Mylar to start decorating our planet, then?

Comment: possibly related, a long conductive thing https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34123/12102 and [1](https://www-spof.gsfc.nasa.gov/Education/wtether.html), [2](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19970011947.pdf), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1002/12102)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's using Earth's magnetic field to create drag. It's one of several passive deorbiting systems.

> An electromagnetic tether uses a conductive tether to generate an electromagnetic force as the tether system moves relative to Earth’s magnetic field.

[NASA: State of the Art of Small Spacecraft Technology, 12. Passive Deorbit Systems](https://sst-soa.arc.nasa.gov/12-passive-deorbit-systems)

[In-Space Propulsion andDe-orbit of Satellites in LEOUsing Electromagnetic Force, Deepak Prem R](https://www.ripublication.com/aasa/aasav3n2spl_07.pdf) has a nice illustration of how this works.

[image]

> As the satellite orbits in the low earth  orbit,  where  there  is  appreciable  density  of  electrons,  a  current  is  passed  in  the conducting  wire.  This  current  interacts  with  the  earth’s  magnetic  field  and  a  force  is developed. By  changing  the  orientation  of  the current  element,  the  direction  of  force  can  be varied  in  accordance  to the  Fleming’s  left  hand  rule.  ...it  can  always  be  used  to raise  or  lower the  altitude.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how that works. The image of the Roll-Out DeOrbiting device (RODEO) shown in your link also shows a length of metalized film but relies on aerodynamic drag. So I've just asked [What fraction of Terminator Tape™'s drag comes from interaction with Earth's magnetic field as a function of altitude? Is it ever important?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41030/12102)

Comment: @uhoh I've added an illustration and paper that explains how it works in more detail. As for what portion is electromagnetic drag and what is aerodynamic drag, I don't know. [Tethers Unlimited's data sheet](http://www.tethers.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/2019-Terminator-Tape.pdf) only says it uses both "neutral particle drag and passive electromagnetics drag".

Comment: excellent, thank you!

Comment: So by the left-hand rule, moving the vertical tape through Earth's magnetic field induces an upward current in it; the current loop is closed through stratospheric plasma (i.e., ionized gas, i.e., conductive); and "back EMF" slows it down just like in an electric motor.